# Color - Changing Backcolor on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, colors, menu, editor

Im using Eclipse to code. There is some problem with it which can be seen on this picture.
[image]
Is there anyway to remove the backcolor or simply change it to white? Because it is hurting my eyes. Thanks!

Comment: Wow, `Vector`s. That's old school.

Comment: I'm sorry for using it instead of `ArrayList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the background color for occurrences:

- Select **Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations**
- Select **occurrences (org.eclipse...)** from the list of **Annotation types**. There are two, but it doesn't matter which one you select since they both get updated.
- Click the rectangle containing the current color and pick another color (or customize your own) in the **Color** dialog.
- Click the **Apply and close** button.

[image: setBackground]

Done! If you want to see the new color for a file that is already open in the editor it seems that you have to reopen it.

---

**UPDATE (3/30/18)**

**My original answer above is wrong.** Based on feedback from the OP in the comments below I have updated and corrected this answer to show how to change the background color for **Warnings** rather than **Occurrences**:

To change the background color for **Warnings**:

- Select **Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations**
- Select **Warnings** from the list of **Annotation types**.
- Click the rectangle containing the current color and pick another color (or customize your own) in the **Color** dialog.
- Click the **Apply and close** button.

[image: setBackgroundWarnings]

The screen shot above was taken on Eclipse Oxygen.3 Release (4.7.3), and obviously your list of **Annotation types** may differ from those in the screen shot.

Comment: My Eclipse is Eclipse Neon 3, and it only has 1 Occurence without the spesification `(org.eclipse....)` but i changed the color to white anyway but it didnt yield any result.

Comment: Update: I changed the `Warning` and it worked instead of `Occurence` , you should edit your answer and ill accept it.

Comment: @Karen Thanks, but it is more appropriate for you to create your own answer and accept that. My answer is incorrect because I had wrongly assumed that the highlights were for occurrences of **Vector**. I also should have mentioned that my solution was produced on Oxygen and might not apply to other releases. Anyway, glad you got it resolved.